# about X command (display variables) in perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging

I am wondering how the big `X` command works in Perl debugger. So I have the following silly.pl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $var1 = 99;
print "$var1\n";
```

I run `perl -d silly.pl`, and step to the 4th line. There I type in the debugger:

```
X var1
```

But nothing shows up. How should I use `X` to display the value of `var1`? (If I remove `use strict;` and don't use `my`, then I can get `X var1` working, but that seems not a solution.)

With Many Thanks!

Comment: The `X` command looks for symbols in the current package's stash. Declaring `$var1` using `my` makes it a lexical variable. Did you mean to use `x $var1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `X` command prints current package variables, e.g. declared as `our`. For lexical scope variables use `x` or `y` (needs `PadWalker` module installed) commands.

Answer (score 2):

hitting **h** in the debugger show this.

```
  V [Pk [Vars]]  List Variables in Package.  Vars can be ~pattern or !pattern.
  X [Vars]       Same as "V current_package [Vars]".
```